# Select all customers and each customer's total orders

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

For each customer, I want to return: id, name, address, city, cap, country and total of orders. Table names are: customers (10 records) and orders (20 records)

I've tried this code, but it doesn't works

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','...','...','...') or die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

$select = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT customers.id,customers.name,customers.address,customers.city,customers.cap,customers.country COUNT(customerid) as TotalOrders FROM customers LEFT JOIN orders GROUP BY customer.id");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $tb = <<<table
    ...{$row['totalorders']}...
    table;
    echo $tb;
}
mysqli_free_result($select);

echo $num_record = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: A missing comma? And a missing join condition. Maybe if you didn't write it all out on one line like that and/or read the error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like...

```
<?php
include('../path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query =
"
SELECT c.id
     , c.name
     , c.address
     , c.city
     , c.cap
     , c.country 
       COUNT(o.customerid) TotalOrders 
  FROM customers c
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.customerid = c.id
 GROUP  
    BY c.id;
";


$result = mysqli_query($db,$query); ** where $db is something like mysqli_connect("myhost", "myusername", "mypassword");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$tb = <<<table
...{$row['totalorders']}...
table;
echo $tb;
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

echo $num_record = mysqli_affected_rows($db);

$db->close();
?>
```

(I'm no php coder)

Comment: got 2 errors: both mysqli_fetch_array() and msqli_free_results() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma missing -

```
customers.country COUNT(customerid)
-----------------^
```

and you have left out an `ON` condition -

```
FROM customers LEFT JOIN orders //ON would be here
```

One thing you should always do is to create and run your queries against your database *before* you put those queries in your code. And always, *always* include error checking.

Comment: always include error checking in development. Remove it in production!

Comment: We never remove it in production because users will find a way to create errors that we have never seen - we just make the errors friendly while logging something more beneficial for the developers.

Comment: But you make yourself vulnerable to attack by revealing error messages to end users

Comment: No - we don't reveal error messages to end users, we provide something friendly for them. And not all errors are attack-able.